# Caesar cipher - digital circuit

Tags: digital-logic

How do I create a combinational circuit that encrypts a message using Caesar's cipher?

And another circuit that decrypts this message?

I thought about using modular arithmetic, but I did not find a simple way to do that either.

Comment: You need an adder. How many characters. 26?

Comment: @JonRB no, i'm using 94 characters. I took the ASC II table as a reference.

Comment: So I need 7 bits to represent those 94 symbols. But the problem is that the sum of the key with the position of the symbol in my alphabet may be greater than my representation. For example, key = 100 and the position of 'a', which is 0

Comment: Can you use the full ASCII table

Comment: Yes I know. But in the ASCII table there are symbols that are not useful to me. Você acha que usar a tabela toda facilitaria ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework without effort.

Comment: @BrianCarlton  I did not find anything very specific in books, so I decided to ask here in the stack. I tried a circuit adder only, but I did not post it here. Maybe that's why you got the impression that I did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I thought about using modular arithmetic**

Yup, that's how you do it, alright.

**but I did not find a simple way to do that either.**

And, if you're going to build it up out of ICs you're not going to find a "simple" way.

Your problem is that (as you've noticed) the 94 characters you've arbitrarily picked (I assume you took the printable characters and excluded the space) are offset by 33 from zero.

So,

1) start by offsetting your characters. Use a pair of 4-bit adders to subtract 33.

2) Convert your key the same way.

3) Add the two using another pair of adders.

4) Use either a pair of 4-bit comparators, a pair of 4-bit adders or an 8-bit comparator to detect a result greater than 93.

5) If step 4 gives a positive result, use another pair of adders to subtract 93 from the results of step 3.

6) Now add 33 to get valid ASCII

That's a preliminary total of 12 16-bit DIPs, which is not simple, but not outrageous, either. Using wirewrap panels I've designed systems with multiple hundreds of chips, so I may be a bit blase about this. YMMV.